# unique key for Patient DataBase

Tags: key, unique

i have a Patient Table that contains:

```
    CREATE TABLE Patient (
    PID                 smallint            NOT NULL   AUTO-Increment,
    PFname              char(30)            NOT NULL,
    PLname              char(30)            NOT NULL,
    Othername           char(30)            NULL,
    DOB                 Date                NOT NULL,
    MainPhone           char(30)            NULL,
    OtherPhone          char(30)            NULL,
    email               varchar(255)        NULL,
    Referral            varchar(255)        NULL,
    notes               varchar(255)        NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (PID),
        UNIQUE KEY  (),
        INDEX (PFname)
        ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

what i choose for unique key?

Answer (score 0):

There's the answer in your own question. For unique key you choose a field or a combination of fields that is supposed to be unique. If the objects don't normally come with fields that are guaranteed to be unique, you create an artificial (often auto-increment) field (like your PID) that is used as a unique key - because it is unique by definition.

As a side note, is your hospital only ever going to have 65k patients? Smallint is a bad choice for PID, in my opinion.